# Função que gera Multiplos Inputs envia só o nº1. Como resolver?

Tags: javascript

A função cria inputs para inclusão de dados
Ao clicar em adicionar, os campos são gerados corretamente

**O problema é que envia sempre o nº 1:**
a) Se só abrir e clicar em Enviar;
b) e mesmo digitando textos.
o que envia:
campo1 = 1
campo2 = 1
campo3 = 1
...

**Como enviar os dados digitados nos campos abertos?**

agradeço antecipadamente

```js
var qtdeCampos = 0;
function addCampos() {
var objPai = document.getElementById("campoPai");
var objFilho = document.createElement("div");
objFilho.setAttribute("id","filho"+qtdeCampos);
objPai.appendChild(objFilho);
document.getElementById("filho"+qtdeCampos).innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='campo"+qtdeCampos+"' name='campo"+qtdeCampos+"' value=''>";
qtdeCampos++;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html><html lang="pt-br">
<head><meta charset="UTF-8">
</head><body>
<form name="gru" method="post" action="grava.php">
<div id="campoPai"></div>
<input type="button" value="adicionar" onclick="addCampos()">
<hr><input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Por que me vez de usar `id` não usa `class`? Ainda evita ter que criar um `id` para cada campo. Não faz muito sentido criar várias `id`s sequenciais se com uma classe vc resolve muito mais facilmente.

Comment: Vc pode colocar um exemplo? agradeço

Comment: Sim, posso colocar um exemplo. Mas, como vc está recebendo os campos no PHP?

Comment: só recebe o nº1 de qq campo. (se enviar em branco ou digitado). A função Não está enviando o texto digitado.

Comment: no grava.php recebe: if(isset($_POST) AND empty($_POST['campo0'])||empty($_POST['campo1'])):
echo'campo 0 = '.isset($_POST['campo0']);
echo'campo 1 = '.isset($_POST['campo1']);
endif;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como havia dito nos comentários, não há necessidade de criar diversos `id`s para cada elemento. Você pode utilizar uma `class` para todos, porque assim fica até mais fácil depois, se quiser, identificar os elementos pelo índice.

Outra coisa, fica mais complicado receber campos criados dinamicamente com nomes diferentes. É bem mais fácil enviá-los como array, e no PHP fazer um `foreach` para pegar os valores de cada índice.

O que precisa fazer é criar os campos com o mesmo `name` em forma de array, acrescentando os colchetes ao `name`:

```
nome="campo[]"
```

Seu código ficaria assim:

```js
function addCampos() {
   var objPai = document.getElementById("campoPai");
   var objFilho = document.createElement("div");
   objFilho.setAttribute("class","filho");
   objPai.appendChild(objFilho);
   document.querySelector("#campoPai .filho:last-child").innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='campo' name='campo[]' value=''>";
}
```

```html
<form name="gru" method="post" action="teste.php">
   <div id="campoPai"></div>
   <input type="button" value="adicionar" onclick="addCampos()">
   <hr>
   <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

O seletor `"#campoPai .filho:last-child"` irá selecionar a última `div` com a classe `.filho` criada.

No PHP você recebe a array `campo` com:

```
$campos = $_POST['campo'];
```

Aí você pode iterar a array pegando os valores de cada campo.

### Edit

Adicionar um limitador de campos para o máximo de 10:

```
function addCampos() {
   
   // conta o número de campos
   var qtdeCampos = document.querySelectorAll("#campoPai .filho").length;

   if(qtdeCampos < 10){   
      var objPai = document.getElementById("campoPai");
      var objFilho = document.createElement("div");
      objFilho.setAttribute("class","filho");
      objPai.appendChild(objFilho);
      document.querySelector("#campoPai .filho:last-child").innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='campo' name='campo[]' value=''>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Agradeço. Estou testando. como incluir um limitador (até 10 campos, por exemplo)

Comment: Ah sim. Vou alterar então. Só um instante.

Comment: Veja o EDIT da resposta. Espero que ajude. :)

Comment: Consegui. Parabéns pela ajuda

Comment: Legal cara! boa sorte!

Comment: Dúvida: qdo o grava.php consiste e tem algum erro, eu salvo as url em session[url+N]. N é um nº igual a qtdeCampos. Mas não consegui inserir na sua função no campo value. Só aceita session[url5], por ex. Vc acha melhor abrir nova pergunta? Agradeço

Comment: A variável `qtdeCampos` é do JavaScript. Não tem como vc usar ela no PHP. O que vc pode fazer é criar um campo hidden e enviar esse valor por ele e pegar no PHP.

Comment: No php está ok. É no java =  document.querySelector("#campoPai .filho:last-child").innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='campo' name='campo[]' value='<?=$_SESSION['url"+(qtdeCampos)+"']?>'>"; Veja onde entra as session numeradas. Assim o usuário não perde a digitação se ocorrer um erro nos processamentos seguintes.

Comment: Mas isso aí tá errado, Não tem como colocar uma variável JS dentro de um código PHP.

Comment: Não tem um jeito? Criar no js uma VAR que monte session[ulr+qtdeCampo] OU algum recurso no js que monte a session? Porque quando coloco a session[url5] funciona OK. Mas ela se repete em todos as linhas da função js.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81229/discussion-between-sam-and-geo).

Comment: Sam, vc pode ver o chat?